# Maven in Eclipse: step by step installation

Tags: eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

I have spent been on the Maven site reading the 5- and 30-minute tutorials, and trialing Maven out for the first time.

I want to install a Maven plugin and use it to start building Maven projects from Eclipse.

Despite an honest effort, I have been unable to find a comprehensive tutorial on any Maven plugin. `M2E`, which seems like the de facto standard, has nothing but broken (or recursive) links on their site.

I can't tell if I even installed the plugin correctly, or how to use it.

Does anyone know of a good step-by-step guide to `M2E` or any other plugin? One that comes with good installation documentation, along with a solid explanation of its features and proper uses?

Comment: I'm in the same boat!, glad you posted this question.. I see this was a few days ago.. where you able to get it working? I already installed maven on my machine but I haven't been able to install the plugin yet.

Comment: If you use Eclipse Juno J2EE m2e is already included.

Comment: @KellySFrench please don't reopen off-topic questions such as tutorial requests.

Answer (score 561, accepted):

(Edit 2016-10-12:  Many Eclipse downloads from https://eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/ have M2Eclipse included already. As of Neon both the Java and the Java EE packages do - look for "Maven support")

**Way 1:** Maven Eclipse plugin installation step by step:

1. Open Eclipse IDE
2. Click Help -> Install New Software...
3. Click Add button at top right corner
4. At pop up: fill up Name as "M2Eclipse" and Location as "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases"
   or 
   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.0
5. Now click OK

After that installation would be started.

**Way 2:** Another way to install Maven plug-in for Eclipse by "Eclipse Marketplace":

1. Open Eclipse
2. Go to Help -> Eclipse Marketplace
3. Search by Maven
4. Click "Install" button at "Maven Integration for Eclipse" section
5. Follow the instruction step by step

After successful installation do the followings in Eclipse:

1. Go to Window --> Preferences
2. Observe, Maven is enlisted at left panel

Finally,

1. Click on an existing project
2. Select Configure -> Convert to Maven Project

Comment: I have tired these steps but not install, I got some error which detail below......Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components) 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.5.0.20140606-0033)

Comment: @Krunal Patel: have you tried from Marketplace?

Comment: I have the same Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.5.0.20140606-0033 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.5.0.20140606-0033) - didn't see the marketplace option under help.

Comment: Eclipse juno doesnt support maven 1.5..still they have not added capability of 1.5

so try 1.4 or 1.3

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.4

Comment: Thanks for such a great description but I am not able to install maven either way. Error saying that "Cannot satisfy dependency:" and "annot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.". I am not sure what's the issue. Please help.

Comment: Did you try "Eclipse Marketplace" for maven installation?

Comment: In Eclipse Neon - there is no **Window -> Preferences**,  option

Comment: Preferences may be present in other place instead of Window menu

Comment: This answer, while being relevant in 2012, is no longer working in the year 2018.  See answer from the  year 2017 below for something that appears to work

Comment: In Eclipse Neon.3 J2EE Maven is already included. To check -> Go to Windows -> Preferences OR File -> New -> Maven Project

Answer (score 39):

IF you want to install Maven in Eclipse(Java EE) Indigo Then follow these Steps :

1. Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software.
2. Type " http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ " & Hit Enter.
3. Expand " Collaboration " tag.
4. Select Maven plugin from there.
5. Click on next .
6. Accept the agreement & click finish.

After installing the maven it will ask for restarting the Eclipse,So restart the eclipse again to see the changes.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. I had tried all the option gven above but none worked for me. Everytime I was getting "can not install due to dependency failure" errror. Your solution worked.

Comment: Thanks so much, me too i tried all other solutions, but none of them worked for me. I followed your steps with Neon instead of Indigo, and it worked :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @mukesh Kumar .........Neon users -- Simply use url - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/neon/

and in the filter type maven and install all the needed software for maven

Answer (score 13):

First install maven in your system and set Maven environment variables

1. M2_HOME:    ....\apache-maven-3.0.5   \ maven installed path
2. M2_Repo:    D:\maven_repo       \If change maven repo location
3. M2:        %M2_HOME%\bin

Steps to Configures maven on Eclipse IDE:

- Select Window -> Preferences
  Note: If Maven option is not present, then add maven 3 to eclipse or install it.
- Add the Maven location of your system

**To check maven is configured properly:**

- Open Eclipse and click on Windows -> Preferences
- Choose Maven from left panel, and select installations.
- Click on Maven -> "User Settings" option form left panel, to check local repository location.

Answer (score 12):

By "use install a Maven plugin and use it" I am sure you are looking for a **Eclipse** plugin that will perform Maven functions within the IDE.  If so, M2E is a good choice.  You will find a lot of help within the Eclipse installation once you install M2E.

That said -- considering that you are starting off using Maven -- it would go a long way to have a good understanding of the basic concepts.  Using M2E could *hide* some of the details which could lead to incomplete or incorrect interpretation of Maven's behavior and therefore problems downstream.

Some good Maven online references are:

- Maven's own documentation -- which you have found.  Be sure to see the [docs of the plugins](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/index.html) that you use
- [Sonatype's Maven book](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/)

Comment: But how do you install M2E on eclipse? (I actually need to install it to MuleStudio.. o.O)

Comment: I am not familiar with Mule Studio.  If it is a plugin for Eclipse 3.7 (a.k.a. Indigo) you should be able to install M2E from the Eclipse Marketplace (Help > Eclipse Marketplace...: Search for "m2e" and select "Maven Integration for Eclipse").  Alternatively you can download it from the M2E web site (http://eclipse.org/m2e/)

Comment: i have installed the plugin and i try to add some sources (artifact or something i think) and the plugin can't find where is installed, netheir i try to download from the plugin and can't find how do it...

Comment: "You will find a lot of help within the Eclipse installation once you install M2E." - but where? There's nothing in the installed help (Help -> Help Contents).

Comment: @MartinSchröder I wrote that over 3 years ago and it was valid then.  I am sorry but I haven't kept up with Eclipse since then.

Answer (score 6):

Check [This](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3)

instead to avoid this error:

> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
>     Software being installed: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.6.1.20150625-2338)
>     Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.0.20150526-2032 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.6.0.20150526-2032) requires 'bundle com.google.guava [14.0.1,16.0.0)' but it could not be found
>     Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.core 1.6.1.20150625-2338) requires 'bundle org.eclipse.osgi 3.10.0' but it could not be found
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.0.20150526-2032 (org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui 1.6.0.20150526-2032)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.6.0,1.7.0)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui 1.6.1.20150625-2338)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core [1.6.0,1.7.0)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: m2e logback appender 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender 1.6.1.20150625-2338)
>       To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui [1.6.0,1.7.0)
>     Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional) 1.6.1.20150625-2338 (org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group 1.6.1.20150625-2338)
>       To: org.eclipse.m2e.logback.appender [1.6.1.20150625-2338]

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18183241/unable-to-install-maven-plugin-for-eclipse)

Comment: Thanks! This solution (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3) works on Kelper!

Comment: Also works on IBM Rational 8.0.3.

Answer (score 5):

You have to follow the following steps in the Eclipse IDE

1. Go to Help - > Install New Software
2. Click add button at top right corner
3. In the popup coming, type in name as "Maven" and location as "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases"
4. Click on OK.

Maven integration for eclipse will be dowloaded and installed. Restart the workspace.

In the .m2 folder(usually under C:\user\ directory) add settings.xml. Give proper proxy and profiles. Now create a new Maven project in eclipse.

Answer (score 3):

I have also come across the same issue and figuredout the issue here is the solution.

Lot of people assumes Eclipse and maven intergration is tough but its very eassy.

1) download the maven and unzip it in to your favorite directory.

**Ex : C:\satyam\DEV_TOOLS\apache-maven-3.1.1**

2) Set the environment variable for Maven(Hope every one knows where to go to set this)

In the system variable:
   Variable_name = M2_HOME
   Variable_Value =C:\satyam\DEV_TOOLS\apache-maven-3.1.1

Next in the same System Variable you will find the variable name called Path:
   just edit the path variable and add M2_HOME details like with the existing values.

```
%M2_HOME%/bin;
```

so in the second step now you are done setting the Maven stuff to your system.you need to cross check it whether your setting is correct or not, go to command prompt and type mvn--version it should disply the path of your Maven

3) Open the eclipse and go to Install new software and type M2E Plugin install  and restart the Eclipse

with the above 3 steps you are done with Maven and Maven Plugin with eclipse

4) Maven is used .m2 folder to download all the jars, it will find in 
Ex: C:\Users\tempsakat.m2

under this folder one settings.xml file and one repository folder will be there

5) go to Windwo - preferences of your Eclipse and type Maven then select UserSettings from left menu then give the path of the settings.xml here .

now you are done...

Answer (score 3):

Maven Eclipse plugin installation step by step:

Open Eclipse IDE
Click Help -> Install New Software
Click Add button at top right corner
At pop up: fill up Name as you want and Location as http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/milestones/1.0
Now click OK
And follow the instruction

Comment: Many of the other answers are many years old as of now (2018). This one worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have just include `Maven` integration plug-in with `Eclipse`:

Just follow the bellow steps:

In `eclipse`, from upper menu item select- `Help` ->click on `Install New Software..`-> then click on `Add` button.

set the `MavenAPI` at name text box and `http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases` at location text box.

press `OK` and select the `Maven` project and install by clicking `next`.

Answer (score 2):

Tried every stuff but this one worked ..
1.  Eclipse -> Help -> Install New Software.
2.  Type " http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ " & Hit Enter.
3.  Expand " Collaboration " tag.
4.  Select Maven plugin from there.
5.  Click on next .
6.  Accept the agreement & click finish.
After installing the maven it will ask for restarting the Eclipse, So restart the eclipse again to see the changes.

Thanks Mukesh for Guiding.

Comment: I liked this option as it will automatically List out the compatible m2e version for the eclipse we are using.Earlier I was trying to get the latest m2e plug-in for juno..but it was giving exception while installing

Answer (score 1):

I was having problems because I was looking to install the Maven plugin on MuleStudio not Eclipse..

[for MuleStudio 1.2 or below do steps (1) and (2) otherwise jump to step (2)]

Instructions for MuleStudio (ONLY versions 1.2 and below):
(1) Help >install new software...

```
Helios Update Site - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/helios/
```

Instructions for MuleStudio (1.3) OR Eclipse:
(2) Help >install new software...

```
Maven -  URL: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases
```

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of Eclipse [(Luna)](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) and Spring Tool Suite [(STS)](http://spring.io/tools/sts/all) come pre-packaged with support for Maven, GIT and Java 8.

Answer (score 0):

I have just include Maven integration plug-in at Eclipse:

Just follow the bellow steps:

- In eclipse, from upper menu item select- "Help" ->click on "Install New Software.."-> then click on "Add" button.
- set the "MavenAPI" at name text box and "http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases" at location text box.
- press Ok and select the Maven project and install by clicking next next.