# Eclipse Maven Plugin Push to Repo

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins

My team has decided to use GitHub with Maven to manage our repository.  I have experience with the Mercurial plugin for Eclipse and BitBucket, but this seems very different.

I managed to download Maven by Help-> Install new software -> Work with: Indigo -> General Purpose Tools -> m2e

So at this point I'd like to connect to the repository at GitHub and then push my content to the repo.

I can't find any tutorials on doing this.  Others seem to be having the same problem; like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-step-by-step)!

Here's a screenshot of my Eclipse setup:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install the [Eclipse:EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/), to let the Eclipse integrate with the Github as a SCM. For further detail please look at the [user guide](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide).

If you would like to do an issue management together with your source code working set. You may use the [Eclipse Mylyn](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) to achieve your requirement. There is a Github Mylyn connector [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Mylyn/Extensions#GitHub_Connector_.28egit-github.29). After you have installed it, during "Add Task Repository..." you will have the following: -

1. Github Gists
2. Github Issues
3. Github Pull Requests

During the committing the source code change set to the version control (SVN/Git/etc) you are able to link the issue from Mylyn connector to it for better management.

Please note, I'm using Maven, SVN as my SCM together with the Eclipse Mylyn with [Redmine](http://www.eclipse.org/mylyn/) by using the [Redmine Mylyn Connector](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Mylyn). They provide me a good result as well.

I hope this may help.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.