# Unable to install Maven plugin for Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, ubuntu-12.04

I'm working on Eclipse 3.7 (indigo) on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I am trying to install the Maven plugin.

Following [this](http://eclipse.org/m2e/download/) page, I added http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases to the Eclipse Install new software prompt box. It recognised the URL and showed "Maven Integration for Eclipse"

But when I click on Next, it gives this error.

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  Missing requirement: Maven Integration for Eclipse (Editors) 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.editor 1.4.0.20130601-0317) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.editor [1.4.0.20130601-0317]
```

What should I do? Please help.

Comment: what flavour of Eclipse Indigo? If it is Standard you might want to try with Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers, which includes more packages and you have a better chance it will come with the missing dependency already bundled

Comment: It's the eclipse installed from the Ubuntu 12.04 repositories.

Comment: I would recommend you try with Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers at http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use the following URL in the "Install New Software" as a repository instead: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3.
I tried it and it works, no more errors.

Answer (score 2):

this is the big problem of eclipse  because mostly eclipse support other Maven

this is plugins for eclipse heilios only

http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3

Comment: Go to Eclipse market place & search  Maven and download according the Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

In Eclipse market place use this URL:-
http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases/1.3/

It will install the maven plugin on eclipse successfully without any error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like somehow it is not able to download the `slf4j` related artifacts , for now you can unselect the checkbox while installing maven plugin .

Please see the attached image.

[image]

If it also don't work then manually download the plugin and drop it in eclipse plugins folder.

Comment: 404 error for the first link that you gave.