# Exception in main thread java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, eclipse, cassandra, datastax, datastax-java-driver

Getting error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureCallback, while running below code. Pls advise which Jar file am missing. I am executing from Eclipse IDE

```
package Datastax;

import com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Host;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Metadata;
import com.datastax.driver.core.Session;


public class DataStaxPOC {
   private Cluster cluster;

   public void connect(String node) {

       cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoint(node).build();

      Metadata metadata = cluster.getMetadata();

      System.out.printf("Connected to cluster: %s\n", metadata.getClusterName());

      for ( Host host : metadata.getAllHosts() ) {
         System.out.printf("Datatacenter: %s; Host: %s; Rack: %s\n",host.getDatacenter(), host.getAddress(), host.getRack());
      }
   }

   public void close() {
      cluster.shutdown();
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      DataStaxPOC client = new DataStaxPOC();
      client.connect("127.0.0.1");
      client.close();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

to setup your environment, you'll need the following resources:

- cassandra-driver-core-2.1.0.jar
- netty-3.9.0-Final.jar
- guava-16.0.1.jar
- metrics-core-3.0.2.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar

(as outlined in this link: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/java-driver/reference/settingUpJavaProgEnv_r.html)

Otherwise you could use Maven if you are using an IDE like Eclipse. See the following link for a dependancy example: http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.1/common/drivers/introduction/driverDependencies_r.html

Note you also need to ensure that the the `start_native_transport: true` is in your cassandra.yaml configuration file also outlined in the above link.

To install Maven into Eclipse I'd recommend using this excellent step-by-step: [Maven in Eclipse: step by step installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

You need to have  cassandra-driver-core-2.0.1.jar , netty-3.9.0-Final.jar , guava-16.0.1.jar , metrics-core-3.0.2.jar , and slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar  on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

i too faced the same issue but after adding the following jars the issue get resolved, 
1. bsh-2.0b4.jar
2. guava-16.0.1.jar
3. jcommander-1.27.jar
4. log4j-1.2.17.jar
5. lz4-1.2.0.jar
6. metrics-core-3.0.2.jar
7. netty-3.9.0.Final
8. slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar
9. slf4j-log4j12-1.7.6.jar
10. snappy-java-1.0.5.jar.

hope this will help you :)