# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback

Tags: maven, cassandra, guava

I'm seeing the following error :

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback
```

when the `cluster.connect()` is called :

```
            String hosts = CassandraClientUtil.getHost();
            String localDC = CassandraClientUtil.getLocalDC();
            Cluster cluster = null;
            if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(localDC))
            {
                cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(hosts.split(","))
                        .withCredentials(CassandraCopsComponentLogger.USER_NAME, CassandraCopsComponentLogger.AUTH_CODE)
                        .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE))
                        .withLoadBalancingPolicy(new TokenAwarePolicy(DCAwareRoundRobinPolicy.builder().withLocalDc(localDC).build())).build();
            }
            else
            {
                cluster = Cluster.builder().addContactPoints(hosts.split(","))
                        .withCredentials(CassandraCopsComponentLogger.USER_NAME, CassandraCopsComponentLogger.AUTH_CODE)
                        .withQueryOptions(new QueryOptions().setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.LOCAL_ONE)).build();
            }

            Session session = cluster.connect();
            CassandraCopsComponentLogger.mappingManager = new MappingManager(session);
```

The pom.xml has the following dependencies :

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
                <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
                <version>16.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.netty</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty</artifactId>
            <version>3.9.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.codahale.metrics</groupId>
            <artifactId>metrics-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>   
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
            <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

I saw a post on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803092/exception-in-main-thread-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror) 
where they recommended to upgrade the guava version to 16.0.1 but that did not help me solve my problem. Some directions from here will be really helpful as I'm new to cassandra. To add more background this thing works as a standalone project, when I include this project as a maven dependency to some other project it raises this runtime error.

Comment: FutureFallback has been introduced in Guava 14, so I suspect the version you specified (16.0.1) is not being taken into account and some very old version is being used instead; can you run "mvn dependency:resolve" and check the actual version of Guava being resolved for your build?

Comment: @adutra And deprecated in Guava 19, then **removed** in Guava 20: https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback.html

Comment: That's true, we are aware of it and working on replacing it: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/JAVA-1328. Currently, the driver cannot work with Guava 20.

Answer (score 24):

[`com.google.common.util.concurrent.FutureFallback`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/FutureFallback.html) is deprecated in Guava 19.0 and removed since Guava 20.0.

Use Guava 19.0 and do not use Guava 20.0 or greater, until you upgrade the Cassandra driver.

Comment: in logs: INFO  GuavaCompatibility.java:135 [{}] Detected Guava < 19 in the classpath, using legacy compatibility layer, makes clear that you can make it work by adding Guava with version < 19. Cassandra driver uses older Guava. It is possible that you are inheriting newer Guava from parent pom.

Answer (score 6):

I updated the Cassandra driver version to latest available and it should fix the issue.

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
   <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.5.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How can it fix. This version of cassandra driver use guava 19

Answer (score 2):

Don't add external guava version . whatever datastax-cassandra-core using only you can put that version . otherwise don't need of that .

Answer (score -1):

If anyone like me didn't know, that there is a new version (4.x) out there with a new and different group id, take a look at the [quickstart](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/4.x/manual/core#quick-start). This new version still uses Guava however it's shaded.

> The driver now requires Java 8. It does not depend on Guava anymore (we still use it internally but it's shaded).

More information can be found in the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver/tree/4.x/upgrade_guide#upgrade-guide).