# How To Create Maven Project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, build

I am a newbie in eclipse.I started working eclipse today onwards.
My requirement is to generate a simple maven project in eclipse.so i put my maven in my c drive and run the mvn -version.it display the version and i assume that maven is installed.

Now i am trying to execute a below command in my cmd.But it always display the error.

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.selva -DartifactId=SampleApplication -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DinteractiveMode=false
```

The error is

```
C:\Users\selva>mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.selva
rtifactId=SampleApplication -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-qui
tart -DinteractiveMode=false
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/pl
ns/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.p
ins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-cle
plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed t
ead artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plug
jar:2.5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/pl
ns/maven-install-plugin/2.4/maven-install-plugin-2.4.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.p
ins:maven-install-plugin:2.4: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-i
all-plugin:2.4 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Fail
to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-instal
lugin:jar:2.4
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/pl
ns/maven-deploy-plugin/2.7/maven-deploy-plugin-2.7.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.p
ins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-de
y-plugin:2.7 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed
 read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-p
in:jar:2.7
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/pl
ns/maven-site-plugin/3.3/maven-site-plugin-3.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.p
ins:maven-site-plugin:3.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site
ugin:3.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to
d artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin:
:3.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/pl
ns/maven-antrun-plugin/1.3/maven-antrun-plugin-1.3.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.p
ins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.3: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-an
n-plugin:1.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed
 read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-p
in:jar:1.3
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/pl
ns/maven-assembly-plugin/2.2-beta-5/maven-assembly-plugin-2.2-beta-5.

[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.p
ins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins
ven-assembly-plugin:2.2-beta-5 or one of its dependencies could not b
esolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plug
:maven-assembly-plugin:jar:2.2-beta-5
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/pl
ns/maven-dependency-plugin/2.8/maven-dependency-plugin-2.8.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.p
ins:maven-dependency-plugin:2.8: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:mave
ependency-plugin:2.8 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved
ailed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-
endency-plugin:jar:2.8
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/pl
ns/maven-release-plugin/2.3.2/maven-release-plugin-2.3.2.pom
[WARNING] Failed to retrieve plugin descriptor for org.apache.maven.p
ins:maven-release-plugin:2.3.2: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven
lease-plugin:2.3.2 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved:
led to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-re
se-plugin:jar:2.3.2
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/pl
ns/maven-metadata.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/m
n-metadata.xml
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-
adata.xml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Con
t to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.47.215]
led: Connection timed out: connect
[WARNING] Could not transfer metadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadat
ml from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to
po.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.47.215] failed:
nnection timed out: connect
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata
l from https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local r
sitory, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval
central has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not
nsfer metadata org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-metadata.xml from/to ce
al (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apac
org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/23.235.47.215] failed: Connection time
ut: connect
[WARNING] Failure to transfer org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml fr
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local reposito
 resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of cent
 has elapsed or updates are forced. Original error: Could not transfe
etadata org.codehaus.mojo/maven-metadata.xml from/to central (https:/
po.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [re
maven.apache.org/23.235.47.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------
-------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------
-------
[INFO] Total time: 04:07 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2014-09-16T16:44:58+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/99M
[INFO] --------------------------------------------------------------
-------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'archetype' in the current project
d in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo]
ilable from the repositories [local (C:\Users\uniphore\.m2\repository
central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with
 -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
ease read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/NoP
inFoundForPrefixException
C:\Users\Selva>
```

I want to create a simple maven project in eclipse.
Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Duplicated question. Solution for you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13640110/3728901

Comment: @dovy,The above link explains how to include maven in eclipse.my question is why my command not executing or build failure and also i use the above link for include maven in my eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

Try out with this steps.

1) In the Eclipse IDE, navigate to File > New > Other… in order to bring up the project creation wizard.

2) Scroll to the Maven folder, open it, and choose Maven Project. Then choose Next.

3) You may choose to Create a simple project or forgo this option. For the purposes of this tutorial, we will choose the simple project. This will create a basic, Maven-enabled Java project. If you require a more advanced setup, leave this setting unchecked, and you will be able to use more advanced Maven project setup features. Leave other options as is, and click Next.

4) Now, you will need to enter information regarding the Maven Project you are creating. You may visit the Maven documentation for a more in-depth look at the Maven Coordinates (http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Maven_Coordinates). In general, the Group Id should correspond to your organization name, and the Artifact Id should correspond to the project’s name. The version is up to your discretion as is the packing and other fields. If this is a stand-alone project that does not have parent dependencies, you may leave the Parent Project section as is. Fill out the appropriate information, and click Finish.

5)You will now notice that your project has been created. You will place your Java code in /src/main/java, resources in /src/main/resources, and your testing code and resources in /src/test/java and /src/test/resources respectively.

6) Open the pom.xml file to view the structure Maven has set up. In this file, you can see the information entered in Step 4. You may also use the tabs at the bottom of the window to change to view Dependencies, the Dependency Hierarchy, the Effective POM, and the raw xml code for the pom file in the pom.xml tab.

Now your java Project with Maven using Eclipse will be created.

If you don't have Maven in Eclipse install m2e .

Comment: could not resolve archetype displays in alert box when click finish and project not created

Comment: If i enable the create a simple project checkbox project created but error in pom.xml file

Comment: CoreException: Could not calculate build plan: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:jar:3.1: ArtifactResolutionException: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:pom:3.1 from/to central (http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): connect timed out