# eclipse do not show the setting.xml for maven - i have downloaded luna full package

Tags: maven, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to set up maven in new eclipse - i have downloaded eclipse luna full package from eclipse site. but the settings xml for maven needs to be defined .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the very first time - there are two ways to do this

1- Using Eclipse - embedded settings of maven

2- Using External Maven -

You can follow steps at - [Maven in Eclipse: step by step installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation)

Then you need to create a simple maven project and clean-install it . It wil download all the basic required jars and all the basic plugins required for clean-compile-install operations.

Then you can start creating maven projects using maven archetypes