# How to use (or integrate) maven pom.xml with an Eclipse Plugin project for dependency management

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, plugins, dependencies

I'm developing a plugin for eclipse, but I'm having issue with including dependencies in my project.

Currently I am able to include hardcoded dependencies like specified here: http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.pde.doc.user%2Fguide%2Ftools%2Feditors%2Fmanifest_editor%2Fdependencies.htm

However, I'd like to include a dependency of a project I've worked on, this way when I make changes to that dependency, I will get the new features in my plugin project.

I really like working with maven pom.xml files, how can I include this in my eclipse plugin project? Or is this even possible? I'd appreciate anyones thoughts or recommendations on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to find a Maven plugin on the Eclipse Marketplace, like [M2E](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation) SO question.

Comment: Sorry perhaps my question was not clear. I know how to use maven, my question is, how to manage dependencies in an Eclipse Plugin project. I'm developing a plugin for Eclipse and there seems there is no way to make this plugin project a maven plugin eclipse project.

Comment: @arabian_albert I don't have very much experience with Maven, but there should be a plugin that allows you to fetch dependencies and create a maven project in eclipse.