# Field xDao in yService required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-rest

Question quite similar to this is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42907553/field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-error-spring-restful-ap) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282735/spring-field-required-a-bean-of-type-that-could-not-be-found-spring-jpa)

And they suggest to use  `scanBasePackages` in the annotation `@SpringBootApplication` and it works to find all beans required for auto wiring.

**Problem Description**

However, in one of the service `CategoryServiceImpl` there is an `autowired` dao `categoryDao` which has `@PersistenceContext` entity manager.

And my spring boot application is unable to find `EntityManagerFactory`
 which is the point where my application is breaking.

It is a very straight forward application( I am trying to learn).
I have two simple projects.

First one is the rest controller and second one is the JPA project to persist entities.

**FIRST PROJECT: REST CONTROLLER PROJECT SETUP**

**Application.java (entry point)**

```
 @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = { 
              "com.example.resourcecontroller",
              "com.example.service",
              "com.example.dao",
              "javax" })
        public class Application {
    }
```

**pom.xml**

```
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>gs-rest-service</artifactId>
<version>0.1.0</version>
```

**SECOND PROJECT: JPA SPRING HIBERNATE**

**pom.xml**

```
   <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate-jpa-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-hibernate-jpa-example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Service class**

```
 @Configuration
    @EnableTransactionManagement
    @ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("com.example.dao"),
          @ComponentScan("com.example.service") })

    @Service
    public class CategoryServiceImpl implements CategoryService {

        @Autowired
        private CategoryDao categoryDao;
    }
```

**DAO**

```
  @Repository
    public class CategoryDaoImpl implements CategoryDao {

        @PersistenceContext
        private EntityManager em;
}
```

**Application Config **

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScans(value = { @ComponentScan("com.example.dao"),
      @ComponentScan("com.example.service") })
public class AppConfig {
   @Bean
   public LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean geEntityManagerFactoryBean() {
      LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean();
      factoryBean.setPersistenceUnitName("LOCAL_PERSISTENCE");
      return factoryBean;
   }

}
```

Comment: Where do you import your AppConfig.java ? (`@Import({... /*list of @Configuration classes*/ .... })`)

Comment: Why do you have an AppConfig class? This is all Spring Boot standard

Comment: @NikolayShevchenko , I think you pointed me to the right direction.  However I am getting the issue that persistence.xml not found. Which seems to be a different issue as springboot by default doesnt support persistence.xml.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli my second project (JPA) was developed without the use of spring boot hence it used AppConfig. Now I am integrating my JPA project with the Springboot managed REST controller.

Comment: Try adding `@EntityScan("package.entities")
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = {"package.repositories"})` onto your spring boot application class