# How can I change my Maven 3.3.9 in Eclipse to Maven 3.2.5?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I want to use Java 1.6 in Maven but 3.3.9 version is not capable of it. I am using Eclipse Mars and Maven 3.3.9 but don't want that because it doesn't support Java 1.6 so I have to degrade my Maven version.

Comment: Window-> preferernces. Type maven in the filter and choose installations

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  "Java 6 reached the end of its supported life in February 2013".   Time to upgrade. 
 JDK 8 is current production, and JDK 9 is on the way. 
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6

Comment: This feels like something you could answer yourself with a very quick search.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven in Eclipse: step by step installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation)

Comment: Maven is capable of using JDK 6 if you need. But you have to go via [Maven Toolchains](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-using-toolchains.html). Using JDK 6 in Eclipse is another thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From eclipse, you can go to Preferences->Maven->Installations. Click the Add button and put in your 3.2.5 install, then click it as the default and try building that way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very easy question you can answer yourself by doing a quick search, e.g. [Maven in Eclipse: step by step installation [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation)