# Writing a plugin for eclipse that Imports maven project

Tags: eclipse, maven, plugins

We are trying to write a plugin for eclipse that imports some maven project.
We saw there is ImportWizard class that can import a file.
Is there functionality that allows importing a maven project that exist on a git repository or even locally?

Comment: What kind of problem are you trying to solve? Importing a Maven project for Eclipse does already exist?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse are you using? Most recent versions have Maven integration out of the box. If yours doesn't, perhaps you can download a different version, or see if this related post is helpful: [Maven in Eclipse: step by step installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation)

Comment: I'm trying to write a plugin for eclipse for personal purposes. The plugin is suppose to automate the process of importing a maven project and make some refactoring changes to the code, varies by the user's choice.