# Maven in eclipse or windows

Tags: java, maven, web

I'm planning to create a java maven web project. I would like to know whether I have to install Maven in windows or install maven in eclipse? I'm using windows 10 and eclipse oxygen. My network has some restrictions so I would be adding a proxy in settings.xml. 
I have already tried creating a maven project in eclipse with maven embedded in my eclipse, but it was giving multiple errors during jars download.
Please suggest me on which way I should proceed and which way is better, whether I should use maven in eclipse or install in windows and use?

Comment: Better to download the standards Version of Eclipse like Eclipse Kepler please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8620127/maven-in-eclipse-step-by-step-installation

Comment: Don't use Kepler, it is very old.

Comment: Yeah. Im using oxygen eclipse. and i tried to use proxy in settings.xml and its working well now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should just try use a different network to create your maven project (for example you can use tethering or ask for permission to get around those network restrictions). After that you should be able to use your maven project even offline.
An alternative would be to just download a maven project and change it to your own.

Comment: So, you suggest me to install maven in os rather than using maven in eclipse

Comment: No, I suggest to use the maven in eclipse, just on a different network

Comment: Yeah. Tried using a proxy in settings.xml and it worked

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you use the embedded Maven in Eclipse, which is part of a standard modern Eclipse installation.

If you get errors with jar downloads, this is probably an issue with your network. Whether putting a proxy in the `settings.xml` is enough to remedy the problem depends on you actual network.

To find out the exact network restrictions, talk to your admin.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 0):

You can try installing maven:

1. Go to maven's website to install/configure maven for your os
2. Set Maven's `settings.xml`
3. Configure Maven in your eclipse, choose the installed maven rather than embedded

If your have any errors, please post them here.

Comment: So yo suggest me to install maven in os and try maven ?

Comment: @Ajith if you use embedded maven in eclipse and there is error, please post the detail error such that someone can help you. Or you can try another approach - install maven in os to see if there is error.